# Adding a SQL parameter has caused query to stop returning results

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK, I've solved one problem and created another, which I could use help with.

The issue I originally had was that I was getting a "must declare the scalar variable" error. The solution was to add the following line to the codebehind:

```
 SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add("username", User.Identity.Name);
```

However, when I did this, everything works perfectly as it should when the user is logged in. They are shown the data that is either flagged as '0' or the rows which are flagged with their username. The problem is that when someone is not logged in, the drop down box (DropDownList2) is then blank. I have no clue why this would happen, so any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

The full codebehind is here:

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class contribute : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection vid2 = new SqlConnection("Data source=COMPUTERTRON2\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=beertrade;Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                bottleformat.SelectedIndex = 0;

                brewerylist.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.DataBind();

                brewery.Text = "Brewery:";
                brewery2.Text = brewerylist.SelectedValue;
                beer.Text = "Beer:";
                beer2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                abv.Text = "ABV:";
                city.Text = "Location:";

                vid2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select case when b.city is null then 'N/A' else [city] + ', ' + [state] end as [city], case when ISNULL(cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)),'') = '' then 'N/A' else cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)) + ' %' end as [ABV] from beer a left join brewery_data b on a.brewery = b.name where a.brewery = (@brewery) and a.name = (@beer)", vid2);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@brewery", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brewerylist.SelectedValue;/**/
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@beer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;/**/
                SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add("username", User.Identity.Name);

                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    /**abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString() + "%";**/
                    abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString();
                    city2.Text = dr["city"].ToString();
                }

                dr.Close();
                vid2.Close();
            }
      }

      protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            string str = "insert into price values ((select bid from beer where name = @beer),(select store_id from stores where name = @store1), getdate(), @price, case when @bottleformat = 0 then '22 oz' when  @bottleformat = 1 then '4-pack or 6-pack'  when @bottleformat = 2 then '750 ml' when @bottleformat = 3 then '32 oz growler' when @bottleformat = 4 then '64 oz growler' end)";

            SqlCommand xp2 = new SqlCommand(str, vid2);
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@var1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brewerylist.SelectedValue;/**/
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@beer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;/**/
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@store1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;/**/
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = TextBox1.Text;/**/
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@bottleformat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bottleformat.SelectedIndex;/**/

            vid2.Open();
            xp2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            vid2.Close();
            Response.Redirect("contribute.aspx");
        }

        protected void brewerylist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) /*adding this got rid of on_selecting error*/
        {
            string str = "insert into test values (@var1,@beer,case when ISNULL(@store2,'') = '' then @store1 else @store2 end,@price)";

            SqlCommand xp2 = new SqlCommand(str, vid2);
            xp2.Parameters.Add("@var1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brewerylist.SelectedValue;/**/

            brewery.Text = "Brewery:";
            brewery2.Text = brewerylist.SelectedValue;
            beer.Text = "Beer:";
            beer2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            abv.Text = "ABV:";
            city.Text = "Location:";

            vid2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select case when b.city is null then 'N/A' else [city] + ', ' + [state] end as [city], case when ISNULL(cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)),'') = '' then 'N/A' else cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)) + ' %' end as [ABV] from beer a left join brewery_data b on a.brewery = b.name where a.brewery = (@brewery) and a.name = (@beer)", vid2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@brewery", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brewerylist.SelectedValue;/**/
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@beer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;/**/
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                /**abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString() + "%";**/
                abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString();
                city2.Text = dr["city"].ToString();
            }

            dr.Close();
            vid2.Close();
         }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            brewery.Text = "Brewery:";
            brewery2.Text = brewerylist.SelectedValue;
            beer.Text = "Beer:";
            beer2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            abv.Text = "ABV:";
            city.Text = "Location:";

            vid2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select case when b.city is null then 'N/A' else [city] + ', ' + [state] end as [city], case when ISNULL(cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)),'') = '' then 'N/A' else cast(a.ABV as varchar(max)) + ' %' end as [ABV] from beer a left join brewery_data b on a.brewery = b.name where a.brewery = (@brewery) and a.name = (@beer)", vid2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@brewery", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brewerylist.SelectedValue;/**/
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@beer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;/**/

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                /**abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString() + "%";**/
                abv2.Text = dr["ABV"].ToString();
                city2.Text = dr["city"].ToString();
             }

            dr.Close();
            vid2.Close();
        }             
    }
}
```

aspx.net page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Submit Beer Data" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contribute.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.contribute" EnableEventValidation="false"%>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <h1 class ="main">Submit Beer Data</h1> Help us collect beer pricing data below.

<br /> 
<br />

<div id="beersearch">   
<div class="border">
    Brewery:   <asp:DropDownList ID="brewerylist" OnSelectedIndexChanged="brewerylist_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="brewery" DataValueField="brewery" Height="29px" Width="279px">
         </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:beertradeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct brewery from beer;" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:beertradeConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [beer] WHERE ([brewery] = @brewery)">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="brewerylist" Name="brewery" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
      <br />
</div>

<div class="border">
Beer:   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="" Height="29px" Width="279px" EnableViewState="false">
        </asp:DropDownList>
      <br />
</div>


<div class="border">
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM stores WITH (nolock) where isnull(new_review,0) = 0 OR ([username] = @username) order by name;" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource3_Selecting">




   </asp:SqlDataSource>

Store:   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" Height="29px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged1" Width="279px">
     </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />

 <span>If store not listed above, submit a new store <a href='Submit_Store'>here</a>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

      <br />
</div>

<div class="border">
Price:   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="29px" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Width="279px"></asp:TextBox>       
      <br />

</div>
<div class="border left">
Bottle size: <br /> 

    <br /><asp:RadioButtonList ID="bottleformat" CSSclass="bottleformat" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                                     <asp:ListItem>22 oz bottle</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem>4-pack / 6-pack</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem>750 ml</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem>32 oz growler</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem>64 oz growler</asp:ListItem>

                                 </asp:RadioButtonList>

</div>
    <br />

<asp:Button class="center" ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click"  Text="Submit Beer Data!" style="height:26px;" />
  <br />

 </div>
  <div id="beerstats">

    <table id="beertable">
        <tr><th><asp:Label ID="brewery" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></th>
          <td><asp:Label ID="brewery2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>
        <tr><th><asp:Label ID="city" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </th>
          <td><asp:Label ID="city2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>
        <tr><th><asp:Label ID="beer" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </th> 
          <td><asp:Label ID="beer2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>
        <tr><th><asp:Label ID="abv" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </th>
          <td><asp:Label ID="abv2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td></tr>

   </table>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

UPDATE:

I didn't quite figure this one out the way I'd like to, so if you have an answer for me, I will still appreciate it. However, I did find a different method which works.

I changed part of my aspx file like:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="UserParam"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM [stores] WITH (nolock) where isnull(new_review,0) = 0 OR ([user] = @username) order by name;" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource3_Selecting">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserParam" Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue="Anonymous" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and add the following to my codebhind (Page_Load):

```
UserParam.Value = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: **WAY TOO MUCH CODE** alert.... pLease show us **only the RELEVANT** pieces for your question - all those empty functions are pointless - don't include. Only include that **only** function** that's causing the error - and please **point out** WHERE in the function that error happens!

Comment: If the user is not logged in, perhaps `User.Identity.Name` is `null`?

Comment: Thanks marc_s. Good info to know, and makes sense. I found a fix for my problem and will post shortly.